# STAR snakemake wrapper with configfile

Tags: snakemake

I'm trying to use the STAR wrapper for snakemake (described [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html)) but would like to include an option for an annotation file using the `--sjdbGTFfile` flag. My goal is to specify a gtf annotation file by referring to a configfile, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Relevant snippet of my config file:

```
annotations: ref_files/cal09_human/GRCh38.103_Cal09.gtf
```

The relevant rule looks like this:

```
rule map_reads:
    message:
        """
        Mapping trimmed reads from {wildcards.sample} to host genome
        """
    input:
        fq1 = "tmp/{sample}_R1_trimmed.fastq.gz",
        fq2 = "tmp/{sample}_R2_trimmed.fastq.gz"
    params:
        index= config["genome_index"],
        extra="--sjdbGTFfile {config[annotations]} \
            --sjdbOverhang 149 \
            --outFilterType BySJout \
            --outFilterMultimapNmax 10 \
            --alignSJoverhangMin 5 \
            --alignSJDBoverhangMin 1 \
            --outFilterMismatchNmax 999 \
            --outFilterMismatchNoverReadLmax 0.04 \
            --alignIntronMin 20 \
            --alignIntronMax 1000000 \
            --alignMatesGapMax 1000000 \
            --outFilterIntronMotifs RemoveNoncanonicalUnannotated \
            --outSAMtype BAM SortedByCoordinate \
            --runMode alignReads"
    output:
        "star_mapping/{sample}_Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam"
    log:
        "logs/star/{sample}.log"
    threads: 20
    wrapper:
        "0.74.0/bio/star/align"
```

I was specifying the config file as if it were within a shell command (like described [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html)), but it's not working:

```
Jun 03 16:49:52 ..... started STAR run
Jun 03 16:49:52 ..... loading genome
Jun 03 16:50:32 ..... processing annotations GTF

FATAL error, could not open file pGe.sjdbGTFfile={config[annotations]}

Jun 03 16:50:32 ...... FATAL ERROR, exiting
```

I ran the following directly in the terminal and it runs just fine:

```
STAR --runThreadN 24 \
 --genomeDir ref_files/cal09_human_star_index \
 --sjdbGTFfile ref_files/cal09_human/GRCh38.103_Cal09.gtf \
 --sjdbOverhang 149 \
 --outFilterType BySJout \
 --outFilterMultimapNmax 10 \
 --alignSJoverhangMin 5 \
 --alignSJDBoverhangMin 1 \
 --outFilterMismatchNmax 999 \
 --outFilterMismatchNoverReadLmax 0.04 \
 --alignIntronMin 20 \
 --alignIntronMax 1000000 \
 --alignMatesGapMax 1000000 \
 --outFilterIntronMotifs RemoveNoncanonicalUnannotated \
 --outSAMtype BAM SortedByCoordinate \
 --runMode alignReads
```

I double checked the I didn't make an obvious mistake like misspecifying the file path in the config file. Does anyone know of a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

```
extra="--sjdbGTFfile {config[annotations]} \
            --sjdbOverhang 149 ..."
```

It seems `{config[annotations]}` is not replaced with the dictionary value but it is instead passed as it is.

If you are on python 3.6+, try using (note the `f`)

```
extra=f"--sjdbGTFfile {config[annotations]} \
            --sjdbOverhang 149 ..."
```

or, old style:

```
extra= "--sjdbGTFfile %s \
            --sjdbOverhang 149 ..." % config[annotations]
```

Comment: Or you can use `format`, as in 
`extra="--sjdbGTFfile {} ...".format(config[annotations])`